# Send large post param in Android

Tags: android, http, post, http-post

How do you send a large (>5MB) post parameter (among other post parameters) in Android?

I'm currently using `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost` and a list of `BasicNameValuePair` to send the post params.

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(someURL);
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "value1"));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", hugeValue));
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

`hugeValue` is a very large string that I would like to read from an `InputStream` and send as I read it. How can I do this?

Comment: You will probably run out of RAM going this route, particularly on smaller phones. You may need to use the lower-level `HttpUrlConnection` stuff from the `java.net` package.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I'm running out of RAM.

Comment: If you control the server side you can write your string to stream, gzip (java.util.zip) it and upload as binary. Some external libraries like apache.mime and commons.io would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CommonsWare is right. HttpUrlConnection and writing direct into the outputstream will solve your memory problem. I've used it in my own application for uploading 10 and more mb of image data.

A good example according your kind of post request is: http://www.java.happycodings.com/Other/code21.html